# SQL Anywhere Long Varchar/Binary Column Length Limited to 32767

Tags: blob, sybase-sql-anywhere

Attempting to set up a database table (Sybase SQL Anywhere 11.0.1) to store user uploaded documents as either BLOBs or base64 encoded strings, but running into an issue where the length of my `LONG BINARY` and `LONG VARCHAR` columns is being limited to `32767`.
Using the following create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE blobTest (
blobCol LONG BINARY,
vcharCol LONG VARCHAR
)
```

The table is added to the database with no issue, however, running a query of the syscolumns table:

```
SELECT cname,coltype,length
FROM sys.syscolumns
WHERE tname LIKE 'blobTest'
ORDER BY cname ASC
```

Yields the result:

```
blobCol, long binary, 32767

vcharCol, long varchar, 32767
```

Storing a value in either of these columns shows that this is indeed the length of the columns, with anything larger than 32Kb* getting truncated.

Looking through the [SAP documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/dbadmin/design-s-3180714.html), it's my understanding that both of these data types should have a limit of roughly 2Gb. I've checked into the server/database configuration options but I can't find anything that looks like it would be limiting the length of these columns, am I missing something?

**-edit-**

The amount that the data was being truncated was not 32000, but 64000, per the admin datasource settings. Further testing showed that the results of:

```
SELECT LEN(vcharCol)
FROM blobTest
```

Would be the correct number of characters expected for an uploaded file.

Comment: Version issue? Which version are you using?

Comment: According to a sys.syshistory query 11.0.1.2376

Comment: Not a sql anywhere user - but may hat have changed? The doc link is for 12.0.1

Comment: All of the versions are listed out in the docs, I thought I had grabbed the link for the ones on v11.0.1, but I guess they're defaulting to the v12 section.

It was the v 11.0.1 section that I was seeing the 2Gb limit though.

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer:

The issue was not with SQL Anywhere, but rather in our server datasource administration settings.

We use ColdFusion 10 on our web server, and the datasources have a `Long Text Buffer` setting which was limiting the size of the string being returned from a query of the database to `64000`

Changing this value to `2000000` solved the issue.